# Prevent printing of output in octave script without adding semicolons everywhere?

Tags: octave

Octave by default prints the result of each assignment, which is quite useful on the terminal and can be quite useful for debugging data evaluation scripts. In order to suppress it,

However, it can also be a major annoyance when working on scripts, forgetting a semicolon, and suddenly having major lags in the GUI due to pages over pages of output for that 10000×10000 matrix.

Is there a way to instead suppress the output *by default*, and instead only echo of assignments, if an explicit trailing `,` is supplied?

Comment: No. Use semicolon as default instruction terminator

Comment: @matzeri It is mostly about preventing my environment to hang because I forgot to use a semicolon somewhere. Even marking missing semicolons as syntax error would be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, octave provides `silent_functions`.

It is false (i.e. 0) by default.

You can set it to 1 to make functions silent, i.e. any evaluations that do not have a semicolon inside the function will not be printed.

Note however, that what you describe, i.e. terminating with a comma, will not display output either when this is enabled. To display output intentionally from a function with this enabled, you will have to use the `disp` command.

From the docs:

```
 -- silent_functions (NEW_VAL, "local")
 Query or set the internal variable that controls whether internal
 output from a function is suppressed.

 If this option is disabled, Octave will display the results
 produced by evaluating expressions within a function body that are
 not terminated with a semicolon.

 When called from inside a function with the "local" option, the
 variable is changed locally for the function and any subroutines it
 calls.  The original variable value is restored when exiting the
 function.
```

---

<sub>PS. Note: this also works for scripts, but **not** for the main console window. Anything you don't terminate with a semicolon in the live console will be printed, regardless of this setting.</sub>

Comment: Having said that, I agree with matzeri, this is not necessarily best practice. Especially if you intend to share your scripts. Think of this more as a convenience toggle during interactive sessions.

Comment: Would work as a workaround, but I'd rather have something along the lines of JavaScript's `"use strict";` -- something that suppresses all *unintentional* output, or even marks it as an error that needs resolving.

Comment: @kdb Marking it an error at runtime would be counterintuitive and counterproductive, since the lack of a semicolon may be intentional. `silent_functions` is hardly a workaround, it's the exact solution envisaged by the octave developers for your question! Beyond that, it seems what you're after is a "linter". I know matlab provides "linting" (i.e. suggestions to improve your code) in its GUI editor ... not sure if octave does this, but I doubt it. Having said that, it should be fairly straightforward to `grep` your source code to detect missing semicolons before the end of a line or comment.

Comment: @kdb also, "use strict;" is actually a very pertinent example. The ECMA team warns copiously that "use strict"; is not a subset of javascript, but actually changes the semantics of the language, so it should not be used as a simple 'addon' to enforce 'strictness' to existing code, as it may break things. If octave was to enable enforcing errors on otherwise valid octave syntax would necessarily have to come with similar warnings about how it might break your code in mysterious and wonderful ways.